# SMTP server error: Authentication required

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ec2, phpmailer

I am a new one for amazon Ec2 instance.Now I want to send mail to client using php code.I installed wamp in my amazon ec2 instance and run these file.

```
 <?php
        use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;


require 'src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'src/SMTP.php';

        //SMTP Settings
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true; 
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; 
        $mail->Host       = "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";
        $mail->Port = 25;
        $mail->Username   = "support@example.com";
        $mail->Password   = "*******";
        //

        $mail->SetFrom('support@example.com', 'Example'); //from (verified email address)
        $mail->Subject = "Email Subject"; //subject

        //message
        $body = "This is a test message.";
        $body = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);
        $mail->MsgHTML($body);
        //

        //recipient
        $mail->AddAddress("myname@gmail.com", "Myname"); 

        //Success
        if ($mail->Send()) { 
            echo "Message sent!"; die; 
        }

        //Error
        if(!$mail->Send()) { 
            echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo; 
        } 

        ?>
```

When run these file and I got some error.

> Parse error: parse error in C:\wamp\www\samplemail\src\PHPMailer.php on line 304

Comment: You're using a very old version of PHPMailer, and you've based your code on an obsolete example, so [upgrade now](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;` and show us the results in order to see why the server doesn't like you.

Comment: There can be multiple reasons for this :

1) Have you confirmed that ports and security groups are blocked.

2) You can also try to use AWS SES

Comment: @Synchro I upgrade the phpmailer.. now I upgrade my question then still I got error

Comment: That parse error means you’re running a very old version of PHP - upgrade that too.

Comment: I am using PHP version 8.0